# Oracle datafile extension .dat or .dbf

Tags: oracle, datafile

I have seen these 2 extensions used for datafiles, `.dat` and `.dbf` while creating and/or altering a `tablespace`. I'm not sure what the difference between the 2 extensions is, or if `.dat` is incorrect.

Here are 2 examples from [Oracle Database SQL Reference 10g Release 2 (10.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7003.htm#i2202468)

`.dat`

```
CREATE TABLESPACE tbs_01 
   DATAFILE 'tbs_f2.dat' SIZE 40M 
   ONLINE;
```

`.dbf`

```
CREATE TABLESPACE tbs_03 
   DATAFILE 'tbs_f03.dbf' SIZE 20M
   LOGGING;
```

Comment: Hey, there's also `undotbs_1a.f` in another example!

Comment: @YasirArsanukaev I did notice that one as well. I wasn't sure if it was an error or something since I've seen the `.dat' and `.dbf` in multiple places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extension and the file path don't really matter – the content does. Moreover, when you use Oracle Managed Files (see ["Using Oracle Managed Files"](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/to_URL?remark=ranked&urlname=http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/omf.htm#ADMIN003) in Database Administrator's Guide), Oracle automatically generates file names, you only have to specify the destination path on the file system or on ASM (see ["Oracle Automatic Storage Management (Oracle ASM)"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/physical.htm#CNCPT1389) in Database Concepts), using initialization parameters such as `DB_CREATE_FILE_DEST` or `DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST`.

Answer (score 6):

The database engine won't care about the extension, it is just a logical name for humans to understand what they are seeing.